# How do I trigger a onclick javascript of a link with AUI?

Tags: javascript, yui, liferay-aui

I have a hidden link that contains a generated javascript snippet that I need to call:

```js
var AUI = YUI;
AUI().use('event', function(A) {
var deleteButton = 46;
A.one('.searchNameSelect').on('keyup', function(e) {
if(e.button == deleteButton){
    A.one('a.deleteSelectedSearch')._node.onclick();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('call successful');" class="deleteSelectedSearch" style="display:none;"></a>
<select name="selectedSearch" size="1" class="searchNameSelect">
 <option value="search">search</option>
 <option value="another-search" selected="selected">another-search</option>
</select>
```

The link is generated with a MyFaces (2.1) commandLink 
`<h:commandLink class="deleteSearch" action="#{search.deleteSelected}"></h:commandLink>`
which generates a onclick javascript: `onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('genertated-formId','generated');`

I tried to trigger the click event with AUI, but without success.

Has anyone a good idea to trigger the onclick Javascript in a more AUI-Style way?

Comment: Can you call the `submitForm` method directly in your event handler?  I'm pretty sure you can't simulate a click on an href like that.

Comment: @MattParker There are two generated, potentially changing, ids inside the submitForm call. I would prefer using the generated JavaScript code over extracting those two generated Ids from the DOM.. It works as it is in the question, I am looking for a more AUI-Compatible way or some way to make it more resilient to changes in YUI, Liferay or JSF...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the 'node-event-simulate' module and call it as

```
A.one('a.deleteSelectedSearch').simulate('click');
```

Here is the modified code

```
var AUI = YUI;
AUI().use('event', 'node-event-simulate', function(A) {
var deleteButton = 46;
A.one('.searchNameSelect').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.button == deleteButton){
        A.one('a.deleteSelectedSearch').simulate('click');
    }
});
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaa8dr3/1/)